# method map() - getting from backend array all object values at once

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, object, key

Im downloading with axios a  backend structure data.

I have something like this: advancedProfile.technologies (array with 5 objects)with keys {title, link, category, date, id}).

and then im rendering a divs with use of map.

The code line is like this :

```
{download.data.advancedProfile.technologies.map(obj=><div>{obj.title}</div>)}
```

With this line I can render all 5 objects from array, but only with one key value.

I am absent-minded, but how i can just map and get all 5 objects with all keys at once ? I dont want to copy and paste all key values separetely.

Comment: What is the desired result? Please clarify.

Comment: You can use something like `<div>{Object.values(obj).map(val => <p key={val}>{val}</p>})</div>`, depending on the HTML structure you're looking for.

Comment: I don't get it. What do you mean by "all 5 objects with all keys at once"? Can you give an example, please?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need values:

```
{download.data.advancedProfile.technologies.map(obj => (
  <div>
    {Object.values(obj).map(value => <div>{value}</div>)
  </div>
))}
```

If you need keys and values:

```
{download.data.advancedProfile.technologies.map(obj => (
  <div>
    {Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value])=> <div>{key}: {value}</div>)
  </div>
))}
```